# Retrieve values in a list in JSON using TSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have this JSON and I want to get all the values in `keyPhrases` to be displayed as a column in TSQL query. Do you know how it can be done?

Desired Output:

| ID | keyPhrases |
| --- | --- |
| 778124772 | banker, good position, friends family |

JSON:

```json
{"documents": [{"id": "778124772", "keyPhrases": ["banker", "good position", "friends", "family"     ], "warnings": []}]}
```

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If you're not using 2016+ then i suggest not doing this in SQL Server, use a different language. if it is 2016+, what have you tried and why didn't it work, or what research havve you done and what didn't you understand about it? There's plenty of resources on how to use T-SQL's `OPENJSON` features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OPENJSON` can help you, so the potential solution can be:

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"documents": [{"id": "778124772", "keyPhrases": ["banker", "good position", "friends", "family"     ], "warnings": []}]}';

SELECT 
        R.id as ID, 
        (SELECT STRING_AGG(value, ', ') FROM OPENJSON(R.kp)) as keyPhrases
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.documents') 
     WITH (id bigint, kp nvarchar(max) '$.keyPhrases' as JSON) R
```

Just to know, `OPENJSON` and `STRING_AGG` are features related to newer versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OPENJSON()` and `STRING_AGG()` as the following:

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{"documents": [{"id": "778124772", "keyPhrases": ["banker", "good position", "friends", "family"     ], "warnings": []}]}';

SELECT JSON_VALUE(T.Value, '$.id') AS ID,
       STRING_AGG(TT.Value, ',') AS keyPhrases
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$.documents') AS T
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Value, '$.keyPhrases') AS TT
GROUP BY JSON_VALUE(T.Value, '$.id');
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b8b8b66a98c0fe8031736098a43e8bc)